# correct displaying columns with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a following input file: text.txt with such context:

```
@@comp1,1111,1111,pass
@@comp2,2222,2222,pass
@@comp3,3333,3333,pass 
@@comp5,5555,5555,pass
```

I display it with awk like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F ',' '{ print $1 }' text.txt > source.txt
awk -F ',' '{ print $2 }' text.txt > exp.txt
awk -F ',' '{ print $3 }' text.txt > obs.txt
awk -F ',' '{ print $4 }' text.txt > verdict.txt
#awk -F ',' '{ print $2 }' text.txt > condition.txt
#awk -F ',' '{ print $3 }' text.txt > exp.txt
#awk -F ',' '{ print $4 }' text.txt > obs.txt
#awk -F ',' '{ print $5 }' text.txt > verdict.txt

#if grep -q "fail" verdict.txt; then
#  pr -m -t source.txt condition.txt exp.txt obs.txt verdict.txt
#else
  pr -m -t source.txt exp.txt obs.txt verdict.txt
#fi
```

Later a new line was observed in file text.txt with a new additional column:

```
@#comp4,wrong val,4444,3134,fail
```

So I have to change my output for correct displaying 5 columns. I tried to use reading line by line, find "@@*" and if there is no "@#*" characters in all lines I display only 4 columns, otherwise - 5. But it didn't work with awk. Is there any way how can I display correctly 5 columns like this:

```
comp1                   1111            1111          pass
comp2                   2222            2222          pass
comp3                   3333            3333          pass
comp5                   5555            5555          pass
comp4     wrong val     4444            3134          fail
```

Comment: I thought to take the first two characters: if it's @@ - then we display 4 columns otherwise (@#) - 5 columns.

Comment: hmm. this new second column just inserted on this position and others simply move on 1 position to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do but maybe this will help:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1 (NF==4 ? OFS : "")} 1' file  
@@comp1         1111    1111    pass
@@comp2         2222    2222    pass
@@comp3         3333    3333    pass 
@@comp5         5555    5555    pass
@#comp4 wrong val       4444    3134    fail
```

or use `awk -F, -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1 (/@@/ ? OFS : "")} 1' file` if you prefer.

If you want the output to look aligned rather than being tab-separated or similar then I recommend you just let `column` do it's job (with a little help from `tr`):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1 (NF==4 ? OFS FS : "")} 1' file |
tr ' ' ',' | column -t | tr ',' ' '
@@comp1             1111  1111  pass
@@comp2             2222  2222  pass
@@comp3             3333  3333  pass
@@comp5             5555  5555  pass
@#comp4  wrong val  4444  3134  fail
```

Comment: actually it works. Just need to add formatting to these columns

Comment: Is it possible here? I mean all verdict is aligned one under one and another columns also like in example.

Comment: Could you please explain me this: {$1=$1 (NF==4 ? OFS FS : "")} Thanks!

Comment: It concatenates `$1` with the result of the ternary expression so when `NF==4` then `$1` becomes `$1<tab>,` (and an effectively en extra field is inserted after `$1` in the output), otherwise it remains just `$1`.